# How to drop duplicates using substring in python?

Tags: python, duplicates

Given a list or Dataframe:

```py
['2020-01-01 12:00:00','2020-01-01 13:00:00', '2020-01-01 14:00:00', '2020-01-02 15:00:00']
```

From the above list **2020-01-01** date is duplicated. I want to drop duplicates and keep the last record.

Sample Result

`['2020-01-01 14:00:00', '2020-01-02 15:00:00']`

Comment: @Manakin Please help me on this

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a neat solution:

```py
times = ['2020-01-01 12:00:00','2020-01-01 13:00:00', '2020-01-01 14:00:00', '2020-01-02 15:00:00']
times_filtered = list({t.split()[0]: t for t in times}.values())
```

This works by exploiting the fact that dictionaries can only hold one item per unique key. Whenever a date (`t.split()[0]`) is repeated, the old value (`t`) is overwritten, guaranteeing that we end up with the right-most times.

Comment: Thank you @jmd_dk that was something new i learnt.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the string to datetime and do a groupby and keep the max date.

```py
data =[{"date":"2020-01-01 12:00:00"},
       {"date":"2020-01-01 13:00:00"},
       {"date":"2020-01-01 14:00:00"},
       {"date":"2020-01-02 15:00:00"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df.set_index('datetime').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).max()
```